# TypeError: date.getTime is not a function when using in angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I am implementing a kendo datetimepicker control in my angular 7 application and getting error TypeError: date.getTime is not a function

The date before i bind to the datetimepicker is /Date(779929200000)/

I have written a method to convert it to date. So I am able to see the datepicker but can see this error on console window of the browser

UI

```
 <label for="inputFax" class="col-md-2  col-form-label header">Inception Date</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{getInceptionDate}}</div>
                        <kendo-datepicker *ngIf="EditMode" [format]="'dd MMM, yyyy'"  [(ngModel)]="getInceptionDate" > </kendo-datepicker>
                </div>
```

component

```
 get getInceptionDate(): string {
        if (this.FundDetails.Entity.INCEPTION_DATE != null) {
            const dateString = this.FundDetails.Entity.INCEPTION_DATE;
            const results = parseInt(dateString.replace(/\/Date\(([0-9]+)[^+]\//i, "$1"));
            const date = new Date(results);
            const month = date.toLocaleString('en-us', { month: 'long' });
            return (month + '-' + date.getFullYear());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using `getTime()` on what you get from  `getInceptionDate()`

Comment: `getInceptionDate()` returns string not a date object. You have to convert the string to date object in order to use `getTime()`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should rename your `getInceptionDate` to something like `formatInceptionDate` and create another getInceptionDate like this :

```
get getInceptionDate(): Date {
    if (this.FundDetails.Entity.INCEPTION_DATE != null) {
        return new Date(this.FundDetails.Entity.INCEPTION_DATE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your function returns a Date object but the return type in the header is a string.